# Oracle create procedure privilege?

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g

If i have a create procedure privilege and don't have update privilege and if in procedure i wrote a update statement so will it update or give me an error?

Comment: it matters to the excutor of the the `proc.`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default Oracle uses the definer rights model for detemining the available privileges for running a procedure. It means that by default the procedure will execute with the privileges of the schema in which it is defined.

So if your schema does not have privilege to UPDATE a table used in the procedure, you will get an error.